# Deleting script tag is still working

Tags: javascript

I have 2 questions.
First,
I have a script tag (not jquery, my own js file) in my page. Then I run my page via apache in browser and delete that tag but the page is still working. why? I also delete all cache and not reload the page.
[delete in browser Elements window]
Second,
What happen when I put two script tag with same name (one in my localhost and another in file system) ? Which one will work?
[image]

Comment: How did you delete that tag? By source inspector? That won't unload the code that is already running. What's "localhost" and "file system" in your 2nd question?

Comment: If you have two non-related questions you should open two questions...

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I updated my question.

Comment: @JordiNebot The questions are related.

Comment: They're on the same topic but non-related. IMHO.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I mean one js file is inside my web app folder, which exist in htdocs. Another file exist inside C drive.

Comment: @NyeinChan on the same machine? Then the latter is absolutely not relevant. The server only sees what you point it to.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I updated my question. There are 2 test.js file. Which one will work? And they are on the same machine.

Comment: @NyeinChan in that case, both, if both can be reached.

Answer (score 2):

After the browser loads the code from a `<script>` tag, it is loaded into the VM and kept there. If it saves some data or functions into global variables, they are independent from the DOM, just like e.g. the `window` object.

All event listeners sent by the code will also persist such removal, effectively meaning the JS is undisturbed by your actions. After a script has been run, it's almost impossible to "turn it off" and remove it from the webpage in a generic way.

If that's your code and you simply want to stop its execution, provide cleanup methods using e.g. `removeEventListener` to stop the browser from calling your code.